# Hide the moves when clicking on a game the "games" pane of a database in ChessBase 15

Tags: chessbase

I would like to hide the moves (circled in red), and arrows as well, in the "games" view of a chessbase (I am using chessbase 15) database when I clicked on one of the games, but I cannot find how to do it :

[image]

Comment: I have the means to answer chessbase questions but i do question if they are really valid for this "forum".

Tht said the documentation for chessbase is reasonably good and the UI is reasonably intuitive. I have only recently installed it and already feel reasonably comfortable with it.

Comment: Honestly, I have the documentation and did not look in it because 90% of the time the answers to questions I face while using chessbase are not in it. I won't even complain about the "quality" of chessbase, I already did.

Answer (score 2):

Would suggest performing a quick search via google
All information can be found at: http://help.chessbase.com/CBase/15

**Hide Notation:**

View Tab > Notation [Untick]

**Hide Movement Arrow:**

http://help.chessbase.com/CBase/15/Eng/index.html?moves_highlighted_with_a_yello.htm